# Why my custom query only returns one result?

Tags: mysql, database, jfactory

```
$dbwsk = JFactory::getDBO();
$querywsk = "SELECT `title` FROM `#__content` WHERE 1";
$dbwsk->setQuery($querywsk);
$rowswsk = $dbwsk->loadResult();
var_dump($rowswsk);
```

I've been working and learning for the whole day and my brain kind of stops working. I am trying to get all values of a column from a certain table, above is the code, but `$rowswsk` only contains 1 string, which is the title of the first article. Why is this? And how should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `loadColumn` instead of `loadResult`. `loadResult` is used when you want to get only 1 value from the query (and is typically used when the query returns just one value), `loadColumn` is used to return a whole column in an array. See Joomla's [official documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) on selecting data from a database.

Comment: @shenkwen There isn't a better solution than this.  Please award this answer the green tick so that your question is deemed resolved within the system. p.s. You don't need [that WHERE 1 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3720735/2943403).